# Set ability.rb but still have admin able to delete user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, action

I'm working in Ruby and in the ability.rb file, I have:

```
when "admin_junior"
  cannot :delete, User
  .
  .
when "admin_senior"
  can :delete, User
  .
  .
end
```

But in my users.rb file I have

```
actions :all, :except => [:edit, :new]
```

I thought that doing this would have it so that when admins login, admin_junior would not be able to delete a User and admin_senior would be able to delete a user.  This currently allows both to view the delete option for a user, and apply it as well.  How do I modify this so that admin_junior will not be able to delete users but admin_senior will?

Sorry...first post I had a typo

Comment: have you tried ? when "admin_junior" cannot :delete, User end

Answer (score 0):

That you have to do yourself. With can? method, you can check your current_user's privileges. If you want to show hide link, you should write like this :

```
<% if can? :delete, @user %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", destroy_user_path(@user), confirm: "Are you sure?", method: delete %>
<% end %>
```

For unauthorized user, you can use code in your controller methods as well :

```
unauthorized! if cannot? :delete, @user
```

you can write  your delete method like this :

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  unauthorized! if cannot? :delete, @user    
  @user.destroy
  # other redirecting stuff
end
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
when "admin_junior"
  cannot :delete, User
  .
  .
when "admin_senior"
  can :delete, User
  .
  .
end
```